# ZeroClipboard just isn't working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typeerror, zeroclipboard, referenceerror

Originally, this post was regarding my attempts to inject ZeroClipboard into web pages by and for use by my Chrome extension, but I've dumbed the scenario down and down and down in a seemingly futile attempt to identify the issue and I **still** can't get it to work.

I'm even having difficulty getting [the actual, documented "Minimal Example](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md#minimal-example)" on ZeroClipboard's own GitHub to work (admittedly, I've modded the source to actually be HTML5-valid, but the exact original didn't work either). Even `test.html`, which is included in the `tar.gz` archive, doesn't work!

**"Minimal Example": Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="d_clip_button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" value="Copy To Clipboard" />
        <script src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
        <script>
            var clip = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById('d_clip_button') );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**"Minimal Example": Console Output**

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function  index.html:11
```

**Info**

- The entire contents of the [`zeroclipboard-1.0.7.tar.gz` archive](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/downloads/detail?name=zeroclipboard-1.0.7.tar.gz&can=2&q=) are in the same directory as `index.html`.
- The `ZeroClipboard.js` file isn't corrupted / incomplete and is being loaded correctly.
- I'm using Chrome v24.0.1312.52

Either I'm missing something really, really obvious here or ZeroClipboard's documentation / functionality is abysmal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've just found out:

- I've [downloaded the ZIP with the JS/SWF from GitHub](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard).
- I've looked into the [examples from Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions#Usage).

That didn't match. I've got a similar error than the original poster of this question.

After I used [the example from GitHub](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard/blob/master/README.md) I've succeeded.

**Conclusion:**

Either use both the example *and* download from Google Code or (which I would prefer), both the example *and* download from GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to specify the path to the swf file :

```
 var clip = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById('d_clip_button'),{moviePath: "/path/ZeroClipboard.swf"} );
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that the variable module was already defined by the framework I use and not meant to be use like ZeroClipboard do. In fact, if you look at the end of the ZeroClipboard.js file, here is what you can see:

```
  if (typeof module !== "undefined") {
    module.exports = ZeroClipboard;
  } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(function() {
      return ZeroClipboard;
    });
  } else {
    window.ZeroClipboard = ZeroClipboard;
  }
```

I just replaced this by the following code to fix the issue:

```
window.ZeroClipboard = ZeroClipboard;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the 2.2.1-dev version: http://datatables.net/download/build/dataTables.tableTools.nightly.js?_=60133663e907c73303e914416ea258d8
I think it should be resolve there.
I would also point out that new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(...) is now the preferred form. The TableTools global is still in 2.2.x, but will be removed in 2.3+.

Answer (score -1):

For loading an external script, inserting a `SCRIPT` element into the page body will *not* immediately load and execute the script. The `appendChild` will return *immediately*, and the script will be loaded *after* the current script execution returns from all functions and goes into idle state.

For this, the `SCRIPT` element's `onload` property can be used to execute a code once the external script is loaded.

```
function inject_zeroClipboard(){
    var path_Root_zeroClipboard = chrome.extension.getURL("plugins/zeroClipboard");
    var element_Head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var element_zeroClipboard = document.createElement("script");
    element_zeroClipboard.src = path_Root_zeroClipboard + "/ZeroClipboard.js";

    element_zeroClipboard.onload = function() {
        ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath(path_Root_zeroClipboard + "/ZeroClipboard10.swf");
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        clip.glue("element_Example");
        clip.addEventListener("click", function(){
            clip.setText(data_Example);
        });
    };

    element_Head.appendChild(element_zeroClipboard);
}
```

Comment: Make sure the `ZeroClipboard.js` file is not corrupted or partially loaded, which prevent the `ZeroClipboard` object from being created. Check the error before the `Uncaught ReferenceError: ZeroClipboard is not defined`.

Comment: Nope. `ZeroClipboard.js` is fully loaded.

Comment: <script>tags will immediately load, unless async is specified, proof here: http://plnkr.co/edit/cobzT4kvEMfBgDeCggNC